# android:button on RadioButton not work

Tags: android, android-radiobutton, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I need custom RadioButton and in my XML:

```
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radBorderBottom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_center_selector"
            android:button="@drawable/ic_border_bottom"   //not see
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onSeletedPosition" />
```

I only see background and not see button here. 
P/s: This issue occurs when I apply newest **Aviary SDK**. But In **Activity** but contain this **XML** I do not change.

Answer (score 1):

Create one **button.xml** file in your **drawable** folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_btn_radio_off_t_holo_light" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_btn_radio_on_t_holo_light" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_btn_radio_off_t_holo_light"/>
```

and finally set **android:button="@drawable/button**

I hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Place your code inside RadioGroup

> `<RadioGroup>
>     <RadioButton
>     />
>   </RadioGroup>`

Comment: yes, that same my code. And when I change on code every thing look good. I don't understand why Aviary make this bug.

Answer (score 0):

try to this code

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radBorderBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onSeletedPosition" />
```

Comment: sorry I need change button in xml, And when I change on code every thing look good. I don't understand why Aviary make this bug.

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading to the latest version of the Creative SDK Image Editor (formerly Aviary).

In older versions of the SDK, some layout elements weren't properly namespaced and could cause problems like this.

## Where to start

1. [You can find out how to get the latest version of the SDK here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html).
2. [You can find out how to integrate the latest version of the Image Editor here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html).